# Can I use a 2.3 PSU for a motherboard that is 2.2?

Tags: power-supply

I'm going to go shopping tomorrow to replace my faulty 2.2 PSU, and I'd like to upgrade to an 80 Plus Gold Standard model. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by 2.3 or 2.2 - maybe this is the model or version number of your specific PSU?

Regardless, I wouldn't worry about it - nearly all PSUs of the same wattage are interchangeable.

Do you know what maximum wattage your current PSU outputs? Try to get something with the same or more wattage. Greater efficiency will help with your electric bill as well.

Also, a single-rail 12v PSU is my personal preference. I look at the 12v amperage to determine the power of the PSU. But that's if you have a higher performance system where 12v current is important...

Comment: I did some research. ATX 2.3 is completely backwards compatible to my knowledge. Go ahead and get a 2.2 or 2.3 - it 99.9% shouldn't matter.